# CancellationToken: why not to use AsyncLocal context instead of passing parameter to every async method?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, cancellation

I see microsoft enforces this pattern for async methods:

```
async Task<object> DoMyOperationAsync(int par1, string par2,..., CancellationToken token=default(CancellationToken))
{
   ...
   CancellationToken.ThrowIfRequested();
   ...
}
```

Every single method should have that ugly `CancellationToken token=default(CancellationToken)` parameter even though most of the time it's not even being used, but just passed through at best.

Why instead of this we cannot just use some sort of CancellationTokenContext, and use it in methods that actually need it?

```
public class CancellationTokenContext
{
    static AsyncLocal<CancellationToken> asyncContext = new AsyncLocal<CancellationToken>();

    public static CancellationToken Current {
        get {
            return asyncContext.Value;
        }
        set {
            asyncContext.Value = value;
        }
    }

    public static void ThrowIfRequested() {
        Current.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    }
}


public class MyClassWithAsyncMethod{

    public async Task<object> DoMyOperationAsync(int par1, string par2,...)
    {
        ...
        CancellationTokenContext.ThrowIfRequested();
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: The vast majority of code couldn't actually use this `CancellationTokenContext` because it would be unpredictable which tasks get cancelled if you trip it -- notably, this can easily involve tasks created earlier by entirely unrelated code. Maintainable code that actually has a need for cancellation would still be required to use its own `CancellationToken` and pass it consistently, defeating the purpose. If you have a code base where these things wouldn't matter you're free to use a pattern like this for your own methods, of course, but as a general approach it's not too hot.

Answer (score 5):

The main reason for not using `AsyncLocal` is that it's much slower. In fact, it's a dictionary lookup, so it should be approximate 20x slower (~ 20ns vs 1ns).

One other factor is: explicit is usually better than implicit. Though I agree it's a very annoying part of async implementation.

Comment: I agree with the design/testability concerns about having static dependencies, but dictionary lookup is O(1)+collision resolutions, comparing in nanoseconds (and therefore 20x) does not seem to be too accurate as it depends on local environment and its current conditions.
Also again usually the token is used in O(n) loops, where it can be assigned to local var before loop starts - but most of the time the token is just passed through the nested async calls

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the main reason is that CancellationToken is a structure. So if you pass it as a parameter, it will be kept in a call stack, without need to allocate memory in heap. But if you use AsyncLocal instead, it will use boxing/unboxing to deal with a cancellation token. In case when async operations are heavily used, i.e. some ASP.NET Core app, it may even affect overall performance because of additional workload for garbage collector.
Other possible problem which I see here, is need to setup up and then restore AsyncLocal for every sub-call which require different cancellation token. For example:

```
private async Task DoSomeWork()
{
    var currentCancallationToken = _ambientCancellationToken.Value;
    _ambientCancellationToken.Value = CancellationToken.None;
    // i.e. we should finish logging no matter of cancellation signal for calling method, for whatever reason
    await _myCustomLogger.AsyncInfo("Do 1st step");
    // restore ambient cancellation token behavior to make next step of async flow
    _ambientCancellationToken.Value = currentCancallationToken;
    await Do1StepOfWork();

    _ambientCancellationToken.Value = CancellationToken.None;
    // ...and here we go again
    await _myCustomLogger.AsyncInfo("Do 2nd step");
    // ...it became annoying...
    _ambientCancellationToken.Value = currentCancallationToken;
    await Do2StepOfWork();
}
```

But from other prospective, if you are sure, that your app (not a public library/framework) will not make several thousandths async flows per second, and you sure, that you will not use mixed cancellation contexts, it seems ok to use such approach.

Comment: I got 2 minuses immediately after posting the answer. Did I say something wrong?

Comment: "But if you use `AsyncLocal` instead, it will use boxing/unboxing to deal with a cancellation token" - I wonder if people see how `AsyncLocal<T>` is generic and just assume that `T` won't be boxed _because it's generic_ (after all, that's an advantage for generics: you have to do something silly in order for value-types to be boxed) - however it turns out that internally `AsyncLocal<T>` just wraps `System.Threading.ExecutionContext..GetLocal` which isn't generic at all and indeed will box the `T` passed-into `AsyncLocal` - which is disappointing.